# Android studio run app not working : Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.android.inspections.lint.IntellijLintIssueRegistry

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1 and gradle version is 2.1.0, project is running on buildToolsVersion "23.0.3". I moment ago studio was working fine. Then i added a image file from "new" - "Image asset" and cleaned project. Studio somehow crashed and restarted. From that moment on i am getting this message in error log. Although compile project feature is working fine.
NOTE : Getting same message even if i am creating a new project and trying to run it.

```
2:34:27 AM IllegalArgumentException: button doesn't exist 0
2:44:52 AM Gradle sync started
2:44:55 AM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.android.inspections.lint.IntellijLintIssueRegistry
2:44:57 AM Gradle sync completed
2:44:57 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
2:45:00 AM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.android.inspections.lint.IntellijLintIssueRegistry
2:45:01 AM Gradle build finished in 4s 135ms
2:45:02 AM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.android.inspections.lint.IntellijLintIssueRegistry
2:45:39 AM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$9
```

Can someone please point me to correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure what actually caused this issue but restarting my system fixed it.